# If you're happy and you know it, clap your hands

Tags: subjunctive-mood

So I am trying to determine what kind of subjunctive is being used in "if...then" utterences such as:
"If you are hungry, eat something."
"If you are tired, go to sleep."
etc.

These phrases seem to have an unspoken "should" as in: "If you are hungry then you should eat something." and "If you are happy and you know it, then you should clap your hands."

Would this be zero conditional because first conditional seems like it would be: "If you are tired, you shall go to sleep."
Second Conditional would be: "If you were happy and you knew it, you should (?) clap your hands."
And Third Conditional would be: "If you had been happy and you had known it, then you should have clapped your hands."

Thoughts?  Is "should" somehow different in this situation than if it were "will/would have/would"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the phrases "first/second/third" conditional. Are they something from your own language, or something from how you were taught English?

Comment: @colin, see [this page](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional2.htm) for a description of these three classes of conditionals.

Comment: Yes, I followed what they meant, from Marina's question. But I've never heard of them before. Your example appears to be a US site, but written by somebody who teaches at a school in Belgium. So is the nomenclature used in the US? or in teaching EFL in Europe? or where. I've never encountered it before.

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Answer (score 2):

There is no implied "should" in *If you are hungry, eat something.*  The main clause, *eat something*, is in the imperative and stands as it is.  I would call the verb of the conditional clause, *if you are hungry*, the present indicative. The subjunctive mood isn't being used.